# QDial set range from 0.00 to 10.00 to widget displays

Tags: c++, qt, qdial

I have a class that connects a Lcd display with a dial and when you rotate the dial you get values on the lcd like this

```
#ifndef SLIDELCD_H
#define SLIDELCD_H

#include <QDial>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include "CustomDial.h"
class SlideLcd: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
SlideLcd(QWidget *parent=nullptr);
private:
CustomDial *dial;
QLCDNumber *lcd;
QVBoxLayout *layout;
};

SlideLcd::SlideLcd(QWidget *parent)
               :QWidget(parent)
{
dial = new CustomDial;
dial->setNotchesVisible(true);
lcd = new QLCDNumber;
connect(dial, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd , SLOT(display(int)));
layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(lcd);
layout->addWidget(dial);
setLayout(layout);
}
```

I know that with QDial::setRange(0,100) you can set the range from 0-100 but is there any way to set ranges like 0.00 to 100.00

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: ok ,here is the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that there's no way to specify `QDial` range using `double`, you should provide an extra slot to catch the `valueChanged` signal, edit the value there and pass the edited value to `display` method of `lcd`.

So, in your widget class:

```
private slots:
  void dialValueChanged(int value);
```

Set dial range to 0-10000 in constructor:

```
dial->setMinimum(0);
dial->setMaximum(10000);
```

then connect the new slot:

```
connect(dial, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this , SLOT(dialValueChanged(int)));
```

The slot definition is like this:

```
void SlideLcd::dialValueChanged(int value)
{
  double v = (double)((double)value / 100);
  lcd->display(v);
}
```

This way, as the dial value changes from 0 to 10000, your lcd will display numbers in range 0.00 to 100.00, accordingly.

Comment: This answer led me in the right direction. What worked for me was:    
`connect(dial, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), lcd, SLOT(display(int)));`
Though I only needed a standard connection, to display values 1-100.